# Comparing family member nodes in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, singly-linked-list, family-tree

I have been working on a family SinglyLinked list. I seemed to be unable to compare the family member.

The node consists of the following:

```
class Node{
public:
    int id, age;
    string name;
    char sex;
    string father, mother;

Node* next;
};
```

The code implementation:

```
Node* currNode = head;
Node* prevNode = NULL;
int index = 1;

//while the current node and the current nodes name is not string one
//n1 and n2 are strings
while(currNode && currNode->name != n1 && prevNode && prevNode->name !=n2){
    prevNode = currNode;
    currNode = currNode->next;
    index++;
}


if(currNode->father == prevNode->name){
    cout<<prevNode->name<<" is the father"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: `prevNode` starts out `NULL` so your condition fails.

Comment: ... and fixing that condition, this still fails when the list is empty or has a single node, the former will result in both `currNode` and `prevNode` as NULL, the latter `prevNode` as NULL. *Neither* can be NULL for your `if()` condition to avoid invoking UB.

Comment: this is probably homework or something, but you would never write a container so specific to what it contains. Nor will you almost ever have occasion to write any container at all on your own.

Comment: Yes it is an assignment, I have to write from scratch, and now it seems that the relationship function of finding a parent is my current problem right now. I do not know a more efficient algorithm to check the childs relation between a parent. And my structure focus is a singlylinked list.